# How to easily toggle a Boolean property?

Tags: python

I want to write a simple toggle for an existing *UI Boolean property*. Every time I run the following code Blender should either show or hide the name of the object in the Viewport, depending on the current state. It works fine, but I wondering if it is really necessary to to call the property 3 times for this easy task.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

if obj.show_name == True:
    obj.show_name = False
else:
    obj.show_name = True
```

Is there a more *elegant* way to write this?

Comment: This is technically a programming question... even though it is about the script, it would be _more_ topical on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can trivially be done as:

```
obj.show_name = not obj.show_name
```

Which basically says: if True, make it not True (i.e. False), else if False, make it not False (i.e. True).

Comment: I was 1 second behind.... Python syntax!

Comment: Would != be valid... just curious?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms No - != is a Boolean operator, it doesn't assign the value to the left hand operand

Comment: Sine when is `!var` possible in Python? It's a SyntaxError in 3.4. What's allowed and does not require a repetition of the variable name is the boolean shorthand for `ixor()`: `obj.show_name ^= True`

Answer (score 4):

Same with xor:

```
obj.show_name = obj.show_name ^ 1
```

Or you can avoid repeating the attribute with:

```
    obj.show_name ^= 1
```

Comment: It provides exact answer to the question "Every time I run the following code Blender should either show or hide the name of the object in the Viewport, depending on the current state."
If this does not really answer the question, whats the point of the first one liner "answer".